# Need help on Hammerjs

Tags: hammer.js

We are utilizing Hammer.js for the double-tap gesture. However, in iPhone Chrome, the double-tap is being recognized as a single tap, causing the expected functionality to not work as intended. Interestingly, the same code performs as expected with desktop mouse double-click events and on iPhone Safari browser(same device).request you to help on this issue.